# Is it possible to forward Windows... windows into Linux? (Like unity/seamless or xypher)

Tags: gnome, xorg, ssh

If this is a "bad question" or otherwise something you mods want to close...

please at least direct me somewhere that could answer it, because that kind of thing happens to me a lot and I end up being stuck...

For instance - I know how to use ssh to forward X windows with...

> ssh -Y -p xxxx user@localhost

Which forwards the users Xinstances to my window.

I was wondering if anyone has gotten really clever and found a way to draw Windows windows in a framebuffer or in wine or something, so that I could use Gnome/Unity/K Desktop managers for windows apps...

Come to think of it, does windows have a "kind of" xypher 
[Thinks about run with credentials]